# Why my CodenameOne-App was not working with HTTPS in ios devices

Tags: codenameone

My App until last two weeks was making all requests using http. All was working fine. since last week , back-end server changed its protocol to HTTPS. I did some corrections in my code, changing http to https. After that, my app stoped to work in ios devices for both ipad and iphone ,but  it was working fine in Android devices for both Tablet and mobiles.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of specifications you have to follow.(More at iOS App Transport Security)
If you want to disable this https restriction, just add this in your plist.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've faced this issue with iOS. I was using HTTPS but there's requirement such as  : Certificate hash algorithm (must be SHA-256 or above) //  
TLS version (must be 1.2) //  
TLS algorithms (must provide Perfect Forward Secrecy)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the signing authority for your server isn't accepted by iOS while it is accepted in Android. This is only a guess though, I will need more details than "doesn't work" to answer the question properly.